# Replace text in a div using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the text in a div tag but I don't know how to do it, can someone help me?

```
<div class="a" onClick="go()">Div</div>

function go(){
$(".a").text() = ":D";}
```

Comment: If you are using jquery `$(".a").text( "D" )`

Comment: If you tried that code you would have gotten a left hand side error, always check your console for errors. Also [read the api documentation of the library you are trying to use](http://api.jquery.com/text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.text()` is a function, not a field.

```js
function go(){
  $(".a").text(":D");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" onClick="go()">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script>
function go(e){
    e.textContent = ':D';
}
</script>
<div class="a" onClick="go(this)">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the current context on click of the element.To replace the text pass the text as the [**text**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) parameter

```js
function go(elem) {
  $(elem).text('D');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" onclick="go(this)">Div</div>
```